# aura component as a help overlay

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to develop an aura component(for Help functionality) similar to the one present in airbnb site(https://www.airbnb.com.au).
In that site, on click of Help, a small popup appears which displays Help content and a close button. The Help windows gets closed if a button is pressed elsewhere on the page or if we click on the close button.
I have developed an aura component as below:

```
<aura:component>    
    <div class="slds-card slds-align_left" >
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <span class="slds-text-heading_large">
                Recommended Help
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid" >
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">                
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small">Search by keyword</span>                        
                    </h2>
                    <lightning:input style="width:300px;" placeholder="Search" type="text" label="" name="Search"/>
                </div>
            </header><br/>            
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            <div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:250px;">
                <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;">
                    <br/>Help content goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-card__footer" style="text-align:center">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Help Centre" />
        </footer>
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

And the simple main page is as below:

```
<aura:component>
        <span style="float:right;font-size:12px;margin-top:6px;cursor:pointer" onclick="{!c.openHelpComponent}">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Help
        </span>
</aura:component>
```

Need to open HelpPage on click of Help link in the above main page. Any pointers on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

In https://www.airbnb.com.au/ site home page, there is Help button as below:
[image]

On click of Help, something similar to below opens:

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using Salesforce's standard [in-app guidance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customhelp_lexguid.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

cannot find the help function you mentioned in airbnb, can you show me where it is?
In addition, I think 'modal' can meet your need.
To make a modal popup, you can check the [overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation)
with showCustomModal method. (check the
Specification)

Comment: Hi Lanjinest, I updated my question.